# Can't mount btrfs on boot

Tags: boot, mount, raid, btrfs

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04 (with a 3.8.13 kernel) that fails to boot if I include in /etc/fstab a mount point for a btrfs volume:

```
/dev/sda3   /home   btrfs   defaults,compress=lzo,noatime,discard   0   0
```

This is a raid1 volume:

```
# btrfs filesystem show
Label: none  uuid: 07489dd8-096a-43a3-9653-55c5948e83a3
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 13.27GB
    devid    1 size 91.76GB used 16.03GB path /dev/sda3
    devid    2 size 91.76GB used 16.01GB path /dev/sdb3
```

dmesg shows this:

```
device fsid 07489dd8-096a-43a3-9653-55c5948e83a3 devid 1 transid 125 /dev/sda3
btrfs: use lzo compression
btrfs: use lzo compression
btrfs: failed to read the system array on sda3
btrfs: open_ctree failed
```

I have to manually run `btrfs device scan`. After that it works fine. Any suggestions on how to fix this?